# How to seal oiled wooden bathroom floor?

Tags: water, wood, waterproofing, sealing, oil

I am buying a house which has a pine floor in the bathroom, treated with Osmo oil.

Having the boards themselves well-oiled will make them waterproof, but there will also be cracks and gaps which develop over time. I am concerned that splashes and damp will make their way down between the cracks and cause mould and other problems.

How should I seal the small gaps in a way which is maintainable and compatible with the oil coating?

Comment: Your concern is valid. The first step, as Emilie describes below is to have a well maintained floor. The next thing is to evaluate the sources of splashes to make sure that seals, caulking, glass doors, etc. are blocking splashes and damp as much as possible. Finally, since this is not a waterproof floor you will need to keep an eye on it after any "wet events" and make sure it's mopped up and dried out quickly.

Comment: An occasional splash landing on a dry floor should not cause problems. If you often splash an already-damp floor, then you get problems. Let things dry out. If you do spill a lot, clean it up and be extra careful until it dries completely.